# Retrieve map attribute from page to page JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary

i am trying to get retrieve attributes which are being put into a map. However i keep getting null when i try to debug it by putting it in an alert. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

First jsp

```
<%
   //Map newSurvey = new LinkedHashMap();
   Map newSurvey = new HashMap();
   newSurvey.put("description", request.getParameter("description"));
   newSurvey.put("startDate", request.getParameter("start_datetime"));
   newSurvey.put("endDate", request.getParameter("end_datetime"));
   newSurvey.put("maxParticipant", request.getParameter("max_participant"));
   newSurvey.put("minAge", request.getParameter("min_age"));
   newSurvey.put("maxAge", request.getParameter("max_age"));
   newSurvey.put("preSurveyText",  request.getParameter("pre_survey_text"));
   request.setAttribute("myMap", newSurvey);
%>
window.location = 'Survey_Questions.jsp';
```

Second jsp (to retrieve) i used a javascript to see if i am able to retrieve it

```
function testGet(){
        <%
        Map myMap = (Map)request.getParameter("myMap");
        String description = (String) myMap.get("description");
        %>
        alert(<%=description%>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

On first page you are using: `request.setAttribute("myMap", newSurvey);`.

So you must have to use `request.getAttribute("myMap");` on second page.

Comment: Explain a bit more about `getParameter` as well in your post as well.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location = 'Survey_Questions.jsp';`

Will just redirect to a page and it will not pass your `request` object to other documents.

Instead you can use below lines of code:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Survey_Questions.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

[`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) helps you to forward your `request` to other pages.

Also, use `getAttribute` instead of `getParameter` as you have used `setAttribute` to set `myMap` on First.jsp.